# Вызов скрипта при определенном разрешении

Tags: javascript

Как изменить условия скрипта, что бы он вызывался при мобильном разрешении ?

```js
    if ($(".about-reasons__slider3").length > 0) {
    var aboutReasonsSlider1 = new Swiper(".about-reasons__slider3", {
    slidesPerView: 4,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    allowTouchMove: true,
    speed: 800,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 5000
    },
    pagination: {
      el: ".about-reasons__pagination",
      type: "bullets",
      clickable: true,
      bulletActiveClass: "isActive"
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".about-reasons__nav3 .-next",
      prevEl: ".about-reasons__nav3 .-prev",
    }
  });
}

//Мобильная версия 
if ($(".about-reasons__slider3").length < 768) {
var aboutReasonsSlider1 = new Swiper(".about-reasons__slider3", {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    slidesPerColumn: 2,
    spaceBetween: 30,
   
    pagination: {
      el: ".about-reasons__pagination",
      clickable: true,
     
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".about-reasons__nav3 .-next",
      prevEl: ".about-reasons__nav3 .-prev",
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: вам нужно что-бы слайдер появился при мобильном разрешении, или что вы имеете ввиду под " что бы скрипт вызывался при мобильном разрешении?

Comment: просто нужно адаптировать уже существующий слайдер, и там не много другие настройки, и когда пользователь заходит с телефона у него вызывался уже другой скрипт с другими разрешениями, мне просто само условие нужно

Comment: @ЕвгенийЕвсюков Посмотрите [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) думаю это решит вашу задачу

Comment: @ЕвгенийЕвсюков Если вам адаптив на свайпер нужно то используйте [документацию](https://swiperjs.com/api/) параметр `breakpoints` создан для адаптации

Comment: @ЕвгенийЕвсюков Есть [демка](https://medium.com/@networkaaron/swiper-how-to-destroy-swiper-on-min-width-breakpoints-a947491ddec8) как включать отключать слайдер на декстоп/мобайл, не уверен что там все правильно, но идея понятна

Comment: не получается.!

Comment: Какие ошибки, что не получается?

Comment: с параметром breakpoints работает только при перетаскивании

Comment: в общем, мне нужно что бы при разрешение < 768 первый скрипт вообще не выполнялся, а выполнялся второй, то есть у меня в стандартном разрешении обычный слайд, когда я захожу с мобильного он должен быть с колонками, то есть slidesPerView: 2,
    slidesPerColumn: 2,

Answer (score 0):

Если делать это с помощью `css` **если я правильно понял и тебе нужно что бы слайдер появился** то  можно изначально задать ему `display:none` а при определенном разрешении с помощью `media` запроса дать ему например `display:block`. Есть вариант сделать это на  `js` с помощью `innerWidth` например `

```js
if (window.innerWidth < 500) {

  // сюда пишешь свой код

}
```

`

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно

Comment: если ответ помог отметь его как правильный

Comment: а если иначе то что используется ? у меня просто эти два условия смешиваются

Comment: какие именно условия и как они могут смешаться

Comment: в описании выше скопирую свой код

Comment: то есть они всё равно смешиваются, как я это узнал ? потому что функция autoplay работает в двух версиях скрипта